Two MapLibre GL JS raster layers pointing to same Geoserver layer
Is it possible to use in MapLibre GL two raster layers on the same time that point to the same Geoserver layer?
I defined two raster layers in maplibreGL pointing to the same Geoserver layer. One are the Spanish provinces and the other is used to highlight a particular province at user request.
So, one layer  with a cql_filter should stay on the top, and on the background stays the other with all provinces.
When both layers are added, the one in the background (all provinces) stays, but on zooming in/out disappear.
Checking console network I see that only the newly added 'provinces_highlighted' layer is called via GetMap.
As you can see in code below, both layers have different ids. And have different named data sources.
But both point to same Geoserver layer. It would be non-sense to duplicate the postGIS table so that I can create 2 different (but same content) layers.
var layer_name='provinces';
var province_name='Girona';

var tiles = ['https://mygeoserver/wms?service=WMS&request=GetMap&format=image%2Fpng&
              layers=hsm:' + layer_name + '&VERSION=1.1.0&transparent=true...'];

map.addSource(layer_name + '_source', {
        "type": 'raster',
        "tiles": tiles
    });

map.addSource(layer_name + '_highlighted_source', {
        "type": 'raster',
        "tiles": tiles
    });     

map.addLayer({
            id: layer_name,
            source: layer_name + '_source',
            'source-layer': layer_name,
            type: 'raster',
            'layout': {
                'visibility': 'visible'
            },
            'paint': {
                'raster-opacity': 1,
                'raster-opacity-transition': { duration: 3000 }
            }
        });           
setTimeout(function()
 {
  map.addLayer({
            id: layer_name + '_highlighted',
            source: layer_name + '_highlighted_source',
            'source-layer': layer_name,
            type: 'raster',
            'layout': {
                'visibility': 'none'
            },
            'paint': {
                'raster-opacity': 0,
                'raster-opacity-transition': { duration: 3000 }
            }
        })    

        var source = map.getSource(layer_name + '_highlighted_source');
                        
      var tiles = source.tiles[0].split('cql_filter=')[0];
      source.tiles[0] = tiles + `cql_filter=province LIKE '${province_name}`;

      map.getSource(layer_name + '_highlighted_source').load();
      map.setLayoutProperty(layer_name + '_highlighted', 'visibility', 'visible');
      map.setPaintProperty(layer_name + '_highlighted', 'raster-opacity', 1);
      map.setPaintProperty(layer_name, 'raster-opacity', .4);

  },1500)                    


You have tags for MapLibre and Mapbox. Did you try/used both? If not, then remove mapbox-gl-js.

For me it works OK, see JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/6ykda7uz/

@TomazicM thanks for the jsfiddle, but zoom in after the settimeout and you will see how one of the layers disappear...

You are right, I haven't checked that. I'll have a look now.

JSFiddle corrected, see answer.

Two things have to be corrected to make this work:

When defining highlighted layer you have to leave out option 'source-layer': layer_name, it should be used only for vector tile source (see https://maplibre.org/maplibre-style-spec/layers/#source-layer).
Method .setTiles should be used to set new titles for highlighted source.

So code should then look  something like this:
setTimeout(function() {
  map.addLayer({
    id: layer_name + '_highlighted',
    source: layer_name + '_highlighted_source',
    type: 'raster',
    'layout': {
      'visibility': 'none'
    },
    'paint': {
      'raster-opacity': 0,
      'raster-opacity-transition': { duration: 3000 }
    }
  });    

  var source = map.getSource(layer_name + '_highlighted_source');                          
  var tiles = source.tiles[0].split('cql_filter=')[0]  + `cql_filter=province LIKE '${province_name}`;
  source.setTiles([tiles]);

  map.setLayoutProperty(layer_name + '_highlighted', 'visibility', 'visible');
  map.setPaintProperty(layer_name + '_highlighted', 'raster-opacity', 1);
  map.setPaintProperty(layer_name, 'raster-opacity', .4);
}, 1500);     

See JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TomazicM/6ykda7uz/

great! did not know about setTiles method, thanks a lot
